# App crash trying to find de sum of all primes below 2,000,000

Tags: c++, math, primes

I trying to solve the Problem 10 from Project Euler, which consists on finding the sum of all prime numbers below 2,000,000. I developed a code to do it but when I run it windows says the App stopped working and then I get:
"Process exited after 3.442 seconds with return value 3221225725"

I have no clue if there is a mathematical error, a logical error or maybe both.

Here is the code(C++):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int vector[1999999];
    long sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<=2000000; i++){ //stores all numbers from 2 to 2,000,000 on the vector
        vector[i] = i+2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<1999999; i++){ //choose a value
        for( int j = i+1; j<1999999; j++){//if there's any multiple of that value in a positon j, vector[j]=0
            if(vector[j]%vector[i]==0){
                vector[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }//after this routine ends the vector stores only prime numbers and zeros

    for(int i = 0; i<1999999; i++){ //sum all values from the vector
        sum = sum + vector[i];
    }

    cout << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int vector[1999999];` is very likely larger than your stack.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i<=2000000; i++){ ` will cause of bounds access. 1999998 is the highest index you can access in your array.

Comment: Look up the Sieve of Eratosthenes and the various improvements to it. Many times as fast as this code.

Comment: Any tips on how can I store so many values? and thanks for your answers

Comment: You don't even need to consider even numbers above 2, so you can special-case 2 and then use an array half the size.

Comment: Why not increment the sum inside the second loop, as you examine the numbers?

Comment: Another hint:  If you use the Sieve of Eratosthenes you can replace your integer array with `std::vector<bool>` which has a much more space efficient implementation.  And as has been mentioned already, it will run much quicker than your code here.

Comment: Thanks for the hints guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on storing so many values, it's better to dynamically allocate memory in heap like:

```
int * vec = new int[2000000];
```

and if you don't need the values anymore, free the memory you allocated like:

```
delete [] vec;
```

But there are lots of optimization to your algorithm, for example [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

It's better not use `vector` as name of an array, because `vector` is a kind of data structure in C++ STL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers, I solved this problem with a different aproach, without using any array. The program is very slow (took nearly 4min to give me the answer) but at least I've finally got the right answer, I gonna try to improve it later.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
long long sum = 17;
int controle = 0;

for(int i = 2000000; i>8; i--){
    for(int j = 2; j<(i/2); j++){
        if(i%j==0){
            controle = 1;
            j = i/2;
        }
       }
    if(controle==0){
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    else{
        controle = 0;
    }
}

cout << sum << endl;

return 0;   
}
```